# Google Chrome fails to open all saved tabs on startup

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I'm getting a weird issue with Google Chrome where, after I shut it down, the next time it starts up, some but not all of the saved tabs are open. The remaining tabs are saved - if I manually type in the address, it says "switch to this tab". But the tab itself isn't actually open.

For example, suppose I exit Chrome with two tabs, A and B. Next time I start it up, it shows only one tab A. If I type in the address for B, it detects B is saved, but there is only one tab open.

I notice clearing cookies fixes this issue temporarily, but only temporarily, because it quickly reappears.

What could be causing this issue, and how to solve it?

Comment: I type in the address for B, it detects B is saved - if you mean that as you type few keywords of B , the exact URL is suggested by the browser then that can happen because it's there in history or you have bookmarked it.

Comment: To restore tabs you can use recently closed tabs feature in history